# GWT Datagrid selection

Tags: gwt, datagrid, row, selection

I would like to reject the selection of a row in a datagrid based on the state of a form. If the form has fields with changed data, I would like the row selection to rejected.

Is there an event I could trap (before selection) and cancel or do I have to implement the logic myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a SelectionChangeHandler on your SelectionModel (it gives you an object which was selected, and you can unselect it), or you can use the CellPreviewHandler on your DataGrid (it gives you a row which was clicked - event.getContext().getIndex() - and you can unselect it in your SelectionModel).

The choice depends on what you want to do after the event: you have to do something obvious in your UI so that users are not confused why clicking on one row selects it, while clicking on another row does not. For example, you can change the background color of unselectable rows as soon as you render your DataGrid, and then show an error message when the wrong row is selected.

Comment: Thanks I implemented CellPreview to trap the mousedown event and rejected it when my form is dirty.